# Selecting attributes in xml using xpath in powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath, scripting

I am trying to use powershell and XPath to select the name attribute shown in the below xml example.

```
     $xml_peoples= $file.SelectNodes("//people") 
     foreach ($person in $xml_peoples){
            echo $person.attributes
            #echo $person.attributes.name
     }
```

Above is the code im running to try and get the name, but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
<peoples>
    <person name='James'>
        <device>
            <id>james1</id>
            <ip>192.192.192.192</ip>
        </device>
    </person>
</peoples>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it a typo? Your xpath has "people" by you have no XML nodes with that name... Is it supposed to be "person" instead?

Comment: Please specify "doesn't seem to work." What actually happened? I think I know what you expected to happen, but it wouldn't hurt to specify that too.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure what **$hub** is, and you started your code from the middle so it's not clear if you properly set **$file** to an XmlDocument object, but I think this is what you want:

```
[System.Xml.XmlDocument]$file = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$file.load(<path to XML file>)
$xml_peoples= $file.SelectNodes("/peoples/person")
foreach ($person in $xml_peoples) {
  echo $person.name
}
```

Answer (score 36):

These two lines should suffice:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.xml'
$xml.selectNodes('//person') | select Name
```

Comment: how can we cast all xml files in a directory as xml objects in Powershell? as in $path = get-childitem -filter *.xml (foreach $file in $path) {...#what goes here}

Comment: If you have a new question: please post a new question. Don't followup on someone else's question in comments.

Comment: sorry, I've posted as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561059/powershell-how-to-cast-all-xml-files-as-xml-objects

Answer (score 25):

How about one line?

`Select-XML -path "pathtoxml" -xpath "//person/@name"`

Comment: That would be perfect, if it wasn't for Select-XML's atrocious handling of namespaces. You'd need to add a namespace parameter (with a dummy namespace name if it uses the default xmlns like most) for every element in the path.  And it's no longer a one-liner (or at least a readable one) if you don't know the namespace value ahead of time.

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that has to work around Select-Xml's garbage namespace handling, here's a one-liner that doesn't care, as long as you know the direct path:

```
([xml](Get-Content -Path "path\to.xml")).Peoples.Person.Name
```

The above will return all matching nodes as well.  It's not as powerful, but it's clean when you know the schema and want one thing out of it quickly.