# How to cast all XML files as XML objects?

Tags: xml, powershell

How can we use PowerShell to cast multiple XML files to objects?

Suppose we have a directory of XML files

```bsh
$xmlfiles = Get-ChildItem C:\Directory -Filter *.xml

foreach ($file in $xmlfiles) {
  [xml]$file Get-Content $_
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed - if we want to query each file as it passes, do we need a nested `foreach`?

I am only casting as XML to make simple queries across multiple documents.
All of my documents have identical schema and I want to select a consistent set of nodes and attributes from every document.

I have tried as suggested in the comments

```bsh
foreach ($file in $xmlfiles) {
  Select-Xml $file -Xpath "//node2"
}
```

but I get a runtime exception:

```
Cannot convert value "sample-document.xml" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error:
"The specified node cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the
specified node is the  wrong type."
At line:1 char:10
+ foreach ($file in $xmlfiles) {
+          ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [], ArgumentTransformationMetadataException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more information on what you want to query these files for? You might not need to cast the file contents as `[xml]` (`Select-Xml` might be an easier option for you)

Comment: oh ok - I didn't know that - I will update my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use [the `Select-Xml` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) to run XPath queries directly against files.

You can pipe `FileInfo` objects from `Get-ChildItem` directly to `Select-Xml`:

```
Get-ChildItem C:\Directory -Filter *.xml |Select-Xml -XPath '//node2'
```

If you need to use `ForEach-Object` or a loop to do further processing, supply the `FullName` property of the file to `Select-Xml`:

```
foreach($xmlFile in Get-ChildItem C:\Directory -Filter *.xml){
    $QueryResult = Select-Xml -Path $xmlFile.FullName -XPath '//node2'
}
```

Comment: This is pretty cool, I can refer to the XML in dotted notation '$QueryResult.node1.node2' and intellisense will tab thru the node names