# Update XML ENTITY with PowerShell (Windows)

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that looks for specific files and folders and the file and folder URLs in contained in an XML file (written to a variable in PowerShell).  I want to be able to look for files in the directory of the current user, but XML files can't contain dynamic variables, so I can't just do the following

```
<URL>C:\Users\$Env:UserName\SomeFile.*</URL>
```

So what I have done is declare an XML Entity as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE config [
  <!ENTITY user "UserName!">
]>
```

BUT, I can not figure out how to reference this entity from PowerShell to update it.  So I can't just do this:

```
$Config.Config.UserName = $Env:UserName
```

Is there anyway to access entities once an XML file is written to a PowerShell variable. I.E. written to a var like this:

```
[xml]$Config = Get-Content ./SomeXML_File.xml
```

Update  -- Here is an example of what I am looking at.  I want to use PowerShell to replace "UserName!" with the current user of the system. So that "&user;" will be read as the current system user when the script gets data from the xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE config[
  <!ENTITY user "UserName!">
]>
<Configuration>
     <Files>
          <URL>C:\Users\&user;\Desktop\NewFolder</URL>
     </Files>
</Configuration>
'''
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selecting attributes in xml using xpath in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17583373/selecting-attributes-in-xml-using-xpath-in-powershell)

Comment: Does the above link may help you? If not,  what is the error or problem when using `.SelectNodes` method?

Comment: I'm getting an overload definition error.  I'm going to update my question with a sample of my xml doc, and maybe that will help.

Comment: As in, it's like the ENTITY isn't even there, but the actual file structure replaces "&user;" with the declared text of "UserName!"...so if I can update "UserName!" then I think it will work....and I'd rather not do it with a get-content -replace() workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I know one should not use string replacements on xml, but this seemed to be the only way to get it working:

Get the content of the XML as single string

```
$xmlText = Get-Content -Path 'D:\SomeFile.xml' -Raw
```

For demo I'm using a Here-String

```
$xmlText = @"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE config[
  <!ENTITY user "UserName!">
]>
<Configuration>
     <Files>
          <URL>C:\Users\&user;\Desktop\NewFolder</URL>
     </Files>
</Configuration>
"@

# create a new Entity tag
$newEntity = '<!ENTITY user "{0}">' -f $env:USERNAME

# replace the current XML Entity with the new one
$xmlText = $xmlText -replace '<!ENTITY[^<>]*>', $newEntity

# load the xml from string to have it resolve the ENTITY username
$xml = [xml]$xmlText

# save the updated XML. Use an absolute path here
$xml.Save("D:\SomeFile.xml")
```

Comment: Thanks all, I'm going to have to abandon this approach, as it doesn't look like what I want to do is possible, the way I want to do it.